# Kubuntu graphical environment is broken

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I am using kubuntu (KDE) and after updating/upgrading my graphical environment was broken. Seems like UI elements are scaled, the names of the files on Desktop disappeared and start button is very small. Other applications are scaled and too big.

It happened after I updated/upgraded and installed qt creator with ncurses.

Please, help

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/logQt.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your desktop theme back to the default Breeze theme. The current gloabal theme you're using is producing this unwanted behaviour.

1. Open the Settings app in KDE Plasma:

   [image: KDE Settings]
2. Navigate to *Appearance* → *Global Themes*:

   [image: Global Themes]
3. Select the *Breeze* theme:

   [image: Breeze theme selection]
4. Tick the *Use desktop layout from theme* option:

   [image: Use desktop layout from theme]
5. Click on *Apply*:

   [image: Apply changes]
6. Log out and log in again.

That's it!
Good Luck!